# How do I install Monodevelop 2.10 or later on 12.04?

Tags: installation, mono

`sudo apt-get install monodevelop` installs MonoDevelop 2.8.x. The official site, http://monodevelop.com/Download, states that "Packages for MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5 not yet available. The latest available version is MonoDevelop 2.6.0.1".

I want to use the F# plugin for MonoDevelop which supposedly is only available for MonoDevelop 2.10.x and latter releases.

How do I install MonoDevelop 2.10.x or latter on my Ubuntu? Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install MonoDevelop 3.0.x (stable) via [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise).

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:directhex/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Please note that Monodevelop 3.0 will be included in Quantal 12.10.

---

> Note: If you are unfamiliar with installing third-party software from PPAs, you may want to refer to these questions:
>
> - [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
> - [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: Glad to have helped, happy coding! :)