# System.TypeLoadException with MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Yesterday I installed MonoDevelop 3.0  by following the steps suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181142/how-do-i-install-monodevelop-2-10-or-later-on-12-04). However when I try to create a new solution, of any of the provided types, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred.

A type load exception has occurred.

System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I posted this question elsewhere, and it was suggested that there might be some compatibility issue between Pangolin and MonoDevelop.

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when trying to start a program called keepass on 12.04.  This solved it:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

Comment: Thanks dgmdan, fixed one problem I had with an application. Fell over on PresentationCore after that though :(