# Where is mono ide?

Tags: mono

I just installed Ubuntu on my local mounted thumb drive.  I went to software and installed mono.  Then I looked in the application folder and saw two icons for mono, one for a terminal which I did not install.  I clicked on the other icon and selected open and nothing happened.  I do I access the mono IDE?

Comment: What mono package did you install? There's the mono runtime and the mono IDE.

Answer (score 3):

MonoDevelop is the IDE typically used for Mono development. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

See: [How do I install Monodevelop 2.10 or later on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181142/how-do-i-install-monodevelop-2-10-or-later-on-12-04)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this, and I believe the question is specifically: where can the executable be found.

As of Ubuntu 14.04, the executable for MonoDevelop will be found at:

```
/usr/bin/monodevelop
```